# Sampling from bins with ratio preservation

Tags: algorithms, integers, sampling, rounding

I have sequence of integers $a_1, a_2, .., a_n$,
let $S_a = \sum_{i=1}^{N}{a_i}$,
for any $k \in (0; 1)$ I need an algorthim to that maps every $a_i$ into another integer $b_i$ with 2 requirements:

1. $S_b = \sum_{i=1}^{N}{b_i}$ is as close as possible to $k \cdot S_a$, ideally $S_b = Round(k \cdot S_a)$
2. $b_i$ is as close as possible to $k \cdot a_i$, ideally $b_i = Round(k \cdot a_i)$

The first requirement is more important.

The problem can be formulated in simpler words as following:
How to generate a sample of a defined size from $N$ bins of different sizes while mantaining the original ratio of elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compute the prefix sum of the $a_i$, multiply all elements by $k$ and round. Now the desired integers are the pairwise differences of that sequence. The first condition is always honored.

E.g. $a=(3,6,2,7,9), k=0.8\to(3,9,11,18,27)\to(2,7,9,14,22)\to(2,5,2,5,8)$.

Comment: This is basically how I do geometry with an imprecise ruler, taking care of not accumulating the error.

Answer (score 0):

If $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}b_i>k\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i$ then $b_n = \lfloor ka_n\rfloor$, else $b_n = \lceil ka_n \rceil$. This requires only one pass through $\{a_n\}$.

Comment: This is equal to the accepted solution.

Comment: @AndreyGodyaev The accepted solution requires three passes through the data.

Comment: That's not true, it is obvious to reduce three passes into one.